# Problems with Weather API from APIXU

Tags: json, api, knockout.js, weather-api

I am just starting to learn API requests and I am trying to display current weather in Toronto using APIXU api calls (here is the documentation: https://www.apixu.com/doc/current.aspx) and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is html:

```
<div class="weather">
  <h3>Toronto Weather Forecast</h3>
  <ul style="margin: 0">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is js:

```
        // Weather API
    function loadData() {
        var weatherAPIXU = "http://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&q=Toronto";
    $.getJSON(weatherAPIXU, function(data) {
        var list = $(".place ul");
        forecast = data.current;
        list.append('<li>Temp: ' + forecast.temp_c + '°C</li>');
    }).error(function(e) {
        $(".place").append('<p style="text-align: center;">Sorry!</p><p style="text-align: center;">Could Not Be Loaded</p>');
    });
};

$('.place').submit(loadData);
```

Once I know how to implement it via JSON, I want to bind it with knockout.js as well

So, if you can give me recommendations on that as well, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In this link it says how to handle ajax request with knockout:  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html.  Also the Knockout mapping plugin can help you (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I haven't get into the mapping yet for this, but thank you for the link - I will look into it. For now I am just very curious why my JSON is not loaded into html. Because I can see the results in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked closer into it and I have found that I didn't load my API at all. So, here is a working solutions for those who might have similar problems.

```
$(document).ready(function loadData() {
    var weatherAPIXU = "http://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=XXXXXXXXXXXX&q=Toronto";
    $.getJSON(weatherAPIXU, function(data) {
        var forecast = data.current.temp_c;
        var weather = $(".weather");
        weather.append(forecast + '° C');
    }).error(function(e) {
        $(".weather").append('Sorry! Not Loaded');
    });
    $('.weather').submit(loadData);
});
```